# html_entity_decode not decoding ASCII

Tags: php

Heres my code:

```
$string = '&#73&#116';
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
echo $string;
```

It should be echoing "It", but its just echoing the ASCII codes. Am I using the wrong function? I also tried htmlspecialchars_decode and it changes nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>Those are not valid entities</del> Actually, they are valid in HTML 4 (and I suppose HTML5 too), but in this case the entities need to be semicolon-terminated for PHP to recognize them:

```
$string = '&#73;&#116;';
```

`htmlspecialchars_decode()` only decodes `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"` (and the last two depend on the quotes flag).

Comment: I've tried html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1') and 
html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES), neither of them work. The string is on my page using ISO-8859-1. I was using $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1')

Comment: @scarhand: Have you tried it with the semicolons? It works for me.

Comment: ahhhh! sorry bolt, the semicolons are the problem. i will explode and implode the string with a semicolon. thanks again!

Comment: $string = preg_replace('/\&\#([0-9]+)/', '&#$1;', $string); =)

Comment: @scarhand: Yeah, I prefer the regex solution.